# Full screen Beamer problems

Tags: beamer, presentations

Is it possible to do full screen which covers the whole screen? When I use full screen option for my pdf file created from beamer presentation, I see some space is being wasted on right and left side of the screen.. But as we know power point in full screen mode covers the entire screen without leaving any black spaces ...Any help would be really appreciated ..

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme {orchid}


    \setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=blue}



\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage {xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig,setspace,subfig,url,amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\title[Random Sampling ] % (optional, use only with long paper titles)
{Random Sampling\\ Case Study}






 \pgfdeclareimage[height=1 cm, interpolate=false]{university-logo}{university-logo-filename}
 \logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}

\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=blue,fg=white}


\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}


% FRAME 1
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
 Random sampling is done to gather data about the population in order to make an inference that can be generalized to the population.\\
\vspace{12pt}
Steps in sampling
\begin{itemize}
\item   Define population $(N)$ to be sampled
\item Determine sample size $(n)$
\item Control for bias and error
\item Select sample
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}




% FRAME 2
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\textbf{Define population to be sampled}: - Identify the group of interest and its characteristics to which the findings of the study will be generalized.\\
\vspace{12pt}
\textbf{Determine sample size $(n)$}:- The size of the sample influences both the representativeness of the sample and the statistical analysis of the data.\\
\vspace{12pt}
\textbf{Control for bias and error}: - Be aware of the sources of sampling bias and identify how to avoid it and decide whether the bias is so severe that the results of the study will be seriously affected.\\
\vspace{12pt}
\textbf{Select sample}:- A process by which the researcher attempts to ensure that the sample is representative of the population from which it is to be selected.
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you testing this on your monitor or using a projector? If the former, this is normal if your monitor has a different aspect ratio from a standard LCD projector. (If it is with the projector itself, then someonr's answer is probably right.)

Comment: Off-topic but you really should clean up your preamble and the packages you are using. `times` is deprecated. You load several packages at least twice and you load packages which you either shouldn't load (e.g. `epsfig`), or which at the least you don't need to load (e.g. `color`, `hyperref`). These are just examples - not exhaustive lists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could it be that the [aspect ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_%28image%29) of the projector isn't matching the presentation? You could try changing to 16:9 by using `\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}`. The right ratio depends on your projector. Btw. please try to use a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme {orchid}


    \setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=blue}



\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage {xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig,setspace,subfig,url,amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\title[Random Sampling ] % (optional, use only with long paper titles)
{Random Sampling\\ Case Study}






 \pgfdeclareimage[height=1 cm, interpolate=false]{university-logo}{university-logo-filename}
 \logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}

\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=blue,fg=white}


\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}


% FRAME 1
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
 Random sampling is done to gather data about the population in order to make an inference that can be generalized to the population.\\
\vspace{12pt}
Steps in sampling
\begin{itemize}
\item   Define population $(N)$ to be sampled
\item Determine sample size $(n)$
\item Control for bias and error
\item Select sample
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}




% FRAME 2
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\textbf{Define population to be sampled}: - Identify the group of interest and its characteristics to which the findings of the study will be generalized.\\
\vspace{12pt}
\textbf{Determine sample size $(n)$}:- The size of the sample influences both the representativeness of the sample and the statistical analysis of the data.\\
\vspace{12pt}
\textbf{Control for bias and error}: - Be aware of the sources of sampling bias and identify how to avoid it and decide whether the bias is so severe that the results of the study will be seriously affected.\\
\vspace{12pt}
\textbf{Select sample}:- A process by which the researcher attempts to ensure that the sample is representative of the population from which it is to be selected.
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```